# scheme word lists eq?

Tags: list, scheme, equals

i've got a problem: I need to find if list equal to the second one, for example:

```
(set%eq? '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))     ===> #t

(set%eq? '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))     ===> #f
```

That examples are correct in my program, but this one is not:

```
(set%eq? (quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three))) (quote ((quote one) (quote two) 
(quote three))))    ====> #f but i need #t
```

what's wrong?
this is my program:

```
(define (set-eq? xs ys) 

(cond ((and (null? xs) (null? ys)) #t) 
       ((null? ys) #f) 
       ((eq? (car xs) (car ys)) (set-eq? (cdr xs) (cdr ys)))
       ((eq? (car xs) (car (reverse ys))) (set-eq? (cdr xs) (cdr (reverse ys))))
       (else #f)))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `equal?`

Comment: what should `(set%eq? '(1 2 3) '(1 3 2))` return? ... you're off-line now, evidently. It's bad etiquette really, to ask and not stay  available for clarifications. :|

Comment: it should return #t, but even don't now how to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in the posted code, and FYI, the procedure tests whether two *lists* are equal, it's not really testing for equality between two *sets*:

```
(define (set-eq? xs ys)
  (cond ((and (null? xs) (null? ys)) #t)
        ((or (null? xs) (null? ys))  #f) ; missing case
        ((equal? (car xs) (car ys)) (set-eq? (cdr xs) (cdr ys))) ; use equal?
        ; deleted unnecessary case here. Anyway, why are you reversing the list?
        (else #f)))
```

Now this will work:

```
(set-eq? '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
=> #t

(set-eq? '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))
=> #f

(set-eq? (quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three)))
         (quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three))))
=> #t
```

In fact, this will work, too:

```
(equal? '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
=> #t

(equal? '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))
=> #f

(equal? (quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three)))
        (quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three))))
=> #t
```

...But this won't work, the *lists* are clearly different:

```
(set-eq? '(1 2 3 4) '(4 1 2 3)) 
=> #f
```

If you intended to test for equality between two *sets*, you have to completely rethink the algorithm. Here's an idea: write a`subset?` procedure that tests if a list is a subset of another list (that is: if all the elements in one list are contained in the other list), and then test whether `(and (subset? l1 l2) (subset? l2 l1))` is true, if that happens, then they're equal according to the *set* definition of equality.

Comment: judging from the name, it's the set equality the OP is after, probably. Hence the attempts to compare in reverse etc. ... unfortunately, they're off-line. :|

Comment: @WillNess but in the question OP states that "I need to find if _list_ equal to the second one". It's hard to tell, and anyway reversing the list won't work...

Comment: '(define (set-eq? xs ys) (cond ((and (null? xs) (null? ys)) #t) ((or (null? xs) (null? ys)) #f) ; missing case ((equal? (car xs) (car ys)) (set-eq? (cdr xs) (cdr ys))) ; use equal? ; deleted unnecessary case here (else #f)))' it's really works but one more question it's not working with numbers like (set-eq? '(1 2 3 4) '(4 1 2 3)) ===>#f but i need #t What should do with it?

Comment: @DenGarif that's because what you wrote is the algorithm for testing equality among _lists_, it won't work for _sets_ (and reversing the list at each step won't do you any good). It's a completely different problem, one idea: write a procedure that tests if a list is a subset of another list (that is: if all the elements in one list are contained in the other list), and then test whether `(and (subset? l1 l2) (subset l2 l1))` is true

Answer (score 0):

Base on the comments from OP it's clear that these are `set-eq?`

```
(set-eq? '(a b c) '(c b a)) ; ==> #t
(set-eq? '(a b c) '(b c a)) ; ==> #t
(set-eq? '() '())           ; ==> #t
(set-eq? '(a b) '(a b c))   ; ==> #f
(set-eq? '(a b c) '(a c))   ; ==> #f
```

If the lists are without duplicates one could iterate the first list and try to find it in the second. If found we recurse with the two lists without the match.

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (rnrs lists))

(define (set-eq? xs ys)
  (if (null? xs) 
      (null? ys) ; #t if both sets are empty, otherwise #f
      (let ((cur (car xs)))        
        (and (memq cur ys) ; first element is found 
             (set-eq? <??> (remq <??> <??>)))))) ; recurse without first in both lists
```

There are ways to get this faster. E.q. Hash the first list and iterate the second. If all matches and `hashtable-size` is the same as the number of iterations it's #t.